# Attribute doesn't update when backgrounded but works fine when run inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, mechanize, sidekiq

I am writing a screen scraper that takes a list of urls from a post, then visits the urls and gets a list of all of the links on the page.  Then it visits all of the links(original and from the scrapes) and gets a list of images.  Everything works fine when I run the job inline (with the exception that it takes 30 sec to finish which is a problem since It takes forever to respond to the API call).   For some reason when I take the same code and use a background worker to run it, there are 2 urls that will never update to completed.  It is always the same 2 urls.

What is weirder is that I am getting the error message

```
3 TID-ov9t89ido WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `search' for #<Mechanize::File:0x007f9d86e77a40>
```

3 TID-ov9t89ido WARN: /app/app/models/scraper.rb:16:in `scrape_images'
/app/app/workers/image_worker.rb:5:in`perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:151:in `execute_job'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:133:in`block (2 levels) in process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `block in invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.1.298/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sidekiq.rb:33:in`block in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.1.298/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:361:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.12.1.298/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sidekiq.rb:29:in`call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in`call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in`call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in`block in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:31:in `with_context'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in`call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in`call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:128:in`block in process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:167:in `stats'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:127:in`process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:79:in `process_one'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:67:in`run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in`block in safe_thread'

That is coming from this code:

```
 def self.scrape_images(uri)
    page = get_page(uri)
    base_url = page.uri.to_s
    images = page.search('//img') || []
    qualify_images(uri, images).push(base_url)
  end
```

I see that Mechanize is not thread safe which I think could be my issue but I don't see how that would give me this error when it works for everything else. Any help would be glorious and thanks for reading.

Comment: I am adding the answer since I didn't find one on SO when I searched.  If Mechanize visits a page that is content type .txt it doesn't return a Page object it returns a File object.  I solved it with a guard clause in my case:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding the answer since I didn't find one on SO when I searched.  If Mechanize visits a page that is content type .txt it doesn't return a Page object it returns a File object.  I solved it with a guard clause in my case:

```
return [] unless page.class == Mechanize::Page
```